# PyGObject and Gtk.TreeStore / TreeView - How do I acces the parent element?

Tags: gtk3, pygobject

I'm working with PyGObject and I successfully setup a TreeStore and a corresponding TreeView. It is just a simple one-column view. It lists all accounts as parents and then you can click the little triangle and it shows the folders. The code looks like this:

```
    accounts_tree_store = Gtk.TreeStore(str)
    treeview_accounts = self.builder.get_object("treeview_accounts")
    treeview_accounts.set_model(accounts_tree_store)
    renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    account_iter = accounts_tree_store.append(None, ["Account1"])
    accounts_tree_store.append(account_iter, ["Folder1"])
    accounts_tree_store.append(account_iter, ["Folder2"])
    accounts_tree_store.append(account_iter, ["Folder3"])
    accounts_tree_store.append(account_iter, ["Folder4"])
    accounts_tree_store.append(account_iter, ["Folder5"])
```

Then I added this so I can get a selection:

```
    selected_tree = treeview_accounts.get_selection()
    selected_tree.connect("changed", Handler().on_tree_select_change)
```

And my function handler looks like this:

```
    def on_tree_select_change(self, widget, *args):
    model, iter = widget.get_selected()            
    if iter:
    print((model[iter][0]))
```

Now all this works just fine. But I want to also print out the parent of the element that is selected. Something like: "Folder2 for Account4". The question is: How can I access the parent? Is there some sort of "get_parent()" function? I didn't find anything in the docs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fuction is called [iter_parent](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeModel.html#Gtk.TreeModel.iter_parent) and will return parent if `iter` has one. It's a `model`'s method.

```
model, iter = widget.get_selected()            
parent = model.iter_parent (iter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works, but when I print(parent) it only prints this:
<Gtk.TreeIter object at 0x7f560ce11b88 (GtkTreeIter at 0x55c95710bb80)>

How can I get the actual name? I tried print(parent[0]) but that gives me an error :
TypeError: 'TreeIter' object does not support indexing

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `print((model[iter][0]))` works, then `print((model[parent][0]))` should work too

Comment: I now have this code:

   `def on_tree_select_change(self, widget, *args):
        model, iter = widget.get_selected()
        print(model.iter_parent(iter[0]))
        print(model[iter][0])`

and it gives me this Error: `TypeError: 'TreeIter' object does not support indexing`

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This method returns TreeIter. It's the same type as 'iter'.  Use it to access model's element, don't print it.

Comment: I didn't pay attention :-(
Of course it works now. Thanks a lot!